# MongoDb - To create a new ObjectId please try `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of using `Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Node.js and mongodb.

In my Node.js application, I am using mongodb and for mongodb operations I am using mongoose.

In the `package.json` file, I have the following dependency:

```
"mongoose": "4.11.9"
```

Although my application works (I can do everything that I want), In the server log I always see the following error message:

> To create a new ObjectId please try `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead
>   of using `Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been fixed for `mongoose 4.11.10` and later versions, so try upgrading your version to get rid of the warning.

This was an unintentional side effect of [#5571](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/5571) because `employees.certifications` happens to be exactly 24 characters long.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var zoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    employees: {
        certifications: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Certifications'}
    }
});

var certificationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    list: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Certification'}]
});

var certificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var Zone = mongoose.model('Zone', zoneSchema);
var Certifications = mongoose.model('Certifications', certificationsSchema);
var Certification = mongoose.model('Certification', certificationSchema);

var newZone = new Zone();
```

For further reading have a look at [issue#5587](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5587) & [issue#5571](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/5571)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there backward compatability for mongoose ? Can I have any problem after upgrading ?

Comment: You shouldn't have any trouble if you upgrade to `4.11.10` as far as it fixes your warning. If you wish to try the very latest version then you will have to check the change-log against your code.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a warning message ( as opposed to an error which would cause your node process to exit ).

**consider this example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
const conn = mongoose.connection;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
  myRef: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'someothercollection'
  }
});

const Test = mongoose.model('test', schema);

const test = new Test({
  myRef: Schema.ObjectId() // or Schema.Types.ObjectId()
});

const test2 = new Test({
  myRef: mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
});

async function run() {
  await conn.dropDatabase();
  let doc = await test.save();
  console.log(doc);
  let doc2 = await test2.save();
  console.log(doc2);
  return conn.close();
}

run();
```

**outputs:**

```
stack: ./49841247.js
mongoose: To create a new ObjectId please try `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of using `Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`. Set the `suppressWarning` option if you're trying to create a hex char path in your schema.
Trace
    at Function.ObjectId (/Users/lineus/dev/Help/mongoose5/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:30:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lineus/dev/Help/mongoose5/stack/49841247.js:19:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
{ _id: 5ad33e173a19606ffa47c95c, __v: 0 }
{ _id: 5ad33e173a19606ffa47c95e,
  myRef: 5ad33e173a19606ffa47c95d,
  __v: 0 }
stack:
```

You can see that:

1. the myRef property of the first document doesn't get set at all and it prints the warning message.
2. In the second document, the myRef property is set properly.

**If you are getting this warning, then most likely, somewhere in your code you are using the wrong method to generate an objectId.**

If you aren't manually generating an objectId incorrectly, check out [the next answer at the time of this edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841968/9111756)

Comment: I ran my example on mongoose 5. There are some subtle differences between 4 and 5 but in this case the overall outcome is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much @lineus